# SQL Server 2012 / 2018 - Invalid object name

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I am developing an application that accesses a database running SQL Server 2012 through the Hibernate framework. However, I cannot figure out how to use my sequence to generate the ID of the new record to add; I get an exception whenever I attempt to save a new object instance to my database table. The class to be saved is the following:

```
package com.xantrix.webapp.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.TableGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Coupons")
public class Coupons implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2788720560904709897L;

    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    /*
    @TableGenerator(
        name="Coupons",
        table="Progressivi",
        pkColumnName="Tipo",
        valueColumnName="Progressivo",
        allocationSize=200
        )
        */
    @SequenceGenerator(name="Coup_Gen", sequenceName="Test_Seq")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="Coup_Gen")
    //@GeneratedValue(generator="Coupons")
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private long id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    @Column(name = "Data")
    private Date dataCreaz;

    @Basic
    private int idDeposito;

    @Basic
    private int qta;

    @Basic
    private double valore;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "IdCliente", referencedColumnName = "CODFIDELITY")
    private Clienti cliente;

    public Coupons()
    {

    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDataCreaz() {
        return dataCreaz;
    }

    public void setDataCreaz(Date dataCreaz) {
        this.dataCreaz = dataCreaz;
    }

    public int getIdDeposito() {
        return idDeposito;
    }

    public void setIdDeposito(int idDeposito) {
        this.idDeposito = idDeposito;
    }

    public int getQta() {
        return qta;
    }

    public void setQta(int qta) {
        this.qta = qta;
    }

    public double getValore() {
        return valore;
    }

    public void setValore(double valore) {
        this.valore = valore;
    }

    public Clienti getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Clienti cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }
}
```

How can I change the SQL query that Hibernate uses to query a Microsoft SQL Server sequence with a Spring MVC 5 Web App?

I cannot use all the Microsoft SQL Server sequences with Hibernate of a Spring MVC 5 Web App because of the error

```
Invalid object name <sequence>.
```

The problem affects Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (but also Microsoft SQL Server 2018).

I am using the Spring MVC 5 framework with Hibernate in Spring Tool Suite 4.
The Server is Apache Tomcat 9.0.19.

I have created a user named

```
WebClient1
```

in SQL Server Management Studio (Microsoft SQL Server 2012).

I have created the following sequence:

```
USE [AlphaShop]
GO

USE [AlphaShop]
GO

/****** Object:  Sequence [dbo].[Test_Seq]    Script Date: 09/07/2019 10:56:28 ******/
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[Test_Seq] 
 AS [bigint]
 START WITH 500
 INCREMENT BY 50
 MINVALUE 500
 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
 CACHE 
GO
```

The following SQL query works successfully in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Test_Seq;
```

but if I try to reach the following URL of the Web App an HTTP Status 500 error appears:
http://localhost:8080/alphashop/coupons/aggiungi/67000023
where the text "67000023" is the ID of an existing user, as shown by the results of the following SQL query:

```
select * from CLIENTI
where CODFIDELITY = 67000023
```

In the console of Spring Tool Suite 4 I can see the latest invoked SQL query:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        next_val as id_val 
    from
        Test_Seq with (updlock,
        rowlock)
lug 10, 2019 12:26:38 PM org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1 execute
ERROR: could not read a hi value
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Il nome di oggetto 'Test_Seq' non è valido.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:256)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1621)

lug 10, 2019 12:26:38 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 208, SQLState: S0002
lug 10, 2019 12:26:38 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Il nome di oggetto 'Test_Seq' non è valido.
lug 10, 2019 12:26:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/alphashop] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work] with root cause
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Il nome di oggetto 'Test_Seq' non è valido.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:256)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1621)
```

As you can see, Hibernate generates the wrong SQL query

```
    select
        next_val as id_val 
    from
        Test_Seq with (updlock,
        rowlock)
```

instead of:

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Test_Seq;
```

that works successfully.

The HTTP Status 500 error, rendered in an HTML page of Apache Tomcat 9 through the Web browser Mozilla Firefox 68.0, is:

```
Type Exception Report
Message Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work
Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
Exception
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1013)
Root Cause
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work
    org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
Root Cause
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
Root Cause
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Il nome di oggetto 'Test_Seq' non è valido.
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:256)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1621)
```

In the object explorer I can see the sequence "dbo.Test_Seq".
The name of the database is AlphaShop.

I tried to execute the following SQL command, but it doesn't solve the problem:

```
ALTER LOGIN WebClient1 WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [AlphaShop];
```

The authentication type of the user is "Authentication of SQL Server".
The user has role "public".

I cannot figure out how to use my sequence to generate the ID of the new record to add; I get an exception whenever I attempt to save a new object instance to my database table.

Please help.
Many thanks in advance.
OS: Microsoft Windows 10 64bit version 2019.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution:
You need to change the Hibernate properties in your "application.properties" file to specify the correct dialect (in my case the correct dialect is "SQLServer2012Dialect"):

```
#Hibernate properties
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.format_sql = true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate
```

instead of the wrong

```
#Hibernate properties
hibernate.dialect =  org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.format_sql = true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate
```